# Why does JavaScript's getElementsByClassName provide an object that is NOT an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, chromium, nodelist

I'm trying to get a list in JavaScript (not using jQuery) of all the elements on the page with a specific class name. I therefore employ the getElementsByClassName() function as follows:

```
var expand_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('expand');
console.log(expand_buttons, expand_buttons.length, expand_buttons[0]);
```

Note that I have three anchor elements on my page with the class 'expand'. This console.log() outputs

```
[] 0 undefined
```

Next, for kicks, I threw expand_buttons into its own array as follows:

```
var newArray = new Array(expand_buttons);
console.log(newArray, newArray.length);
```

This suddenly outputs

```
[NodeList[3]] 1
```

and I can click through the nodelist and see the attributes of the three 'expand' anchor elements on the page. It's also worth noting that I was able to get my code working in a [w3schools test page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_getelementsbyname).

It may also be of note that my use of document.getElementsByName actually does output (to the console) an array of elements, but when I ask for its length, it tells me 0. Similarly, if I try to access an array element using `array_name[0]` as normal, it outputs 'undefined', despite there clearly being an element inside of an array when I print the object to the console.

Does anybody have any idea why this might be? I just want to loop through DOM elements, and I'm avoiding jQuery at the moment because I'm trying to practice coding with vanilla JavaScript.

Thanks,

ParagonRG

Comment: check if that function is not changed

Comment: Are you running your code after the DOM is constructed or before?

Comment: [Be careful with w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: More [explanation](http://alebelcor.blogspot.com/2011/03/htmlcollections-nodelists.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not so much a JavaScript thing as it is a web browser thing. That API is supplied by a native object (the `document` object), and by the DOM spec it returns a NodeList object. You can treat a NodeList like an array, and it's similar, but distinctly different (as you've noticed).

You can always copy a NodeList to a new array:

```
var nodeArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(theNodeList, 0);
```

or in modern ES2015 environments:

```
var nodeArr = Array.from(theNodeList);
```

JavaScript always exists in some runtime context, and the context can include all sorts of APIs that provide facilities to JavaScript code. A web browser is one of those contexts. The DOM is specified in a way that's not especially partial to JavaScript; it's a language-neutral interface definition.

I guess the short version of this answer would be, "because it just does."

Comment: If you can use ES2015/ES6 then `Array.from` is your friend

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't return an array because the object it [returns is "live"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), specifically it is a live [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList):

> In most cases, the NodeList is a live collection. This means that changes on the DOM tree are going to be reflected on the collection.