# Splice is not a function error

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am getting the error tweetParentsArray.splice is not a function
    at injectFactCheck

```
function injectFactCheck(){
    var index = 5;
    var tweetParentsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("js-stream-tweet");
    if(tweetParentsArray.length == 0){return;}
    tweetParentsArray.splice(0, index);
```

When I console.log the tweetParentsArray it appears to be a normal array to me so I am not sure as to why this function would not exist on this object.

Comment: You are actually getting an Object from getElementsByClassName. Array and Object are two different types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064562/why-does-javascripts-getelementsbyclassname-provide-an-object-that-is-not-an-ar check this stackoverflow question & answer

Comment: Do you want to delete the html elements from DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is not an array. You can use `Array.prototype.slice.call(htmlCollection)` to convert it to array and then perform further calculation with array.

```
function injectFactCheck(){
  var index = 5;
  var htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("js-stream-tweet");
  var tweetParentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(htmlCollection);
  if (tweetParentsArray.length == 0){return;}
  tweetParentsArray.splice(0, index);
}
```

See more in this question: [Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array)

Comment: If you can use ES2015/ES6 then `Array.from` is your friend

Comment: @mfeineis or spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: true :-), although it is hard to google for `...` when you see it in code and don't have a clue what it's for *g*

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` return a HTMLCollection. It does not have splice method.
You can convert the HTMLCollection to array to use the splice method.

```
var tweetParentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("js-stream-tweet"))
    if (tweetParentsArray.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    tweetParentsArray.splice(0, index)
```

Answer (score 0):

This in fact is an HTMLCollection, which is "array-like". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection for more details.